# Is there any way to use a .env variable in a makefile?

Tags: docker, makefile, environment-variables

I have a test pipeline that is set up in a docker container. Faux-environment variables are passed into the environment using a .env file.

In my .env file, I have this line:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dbpassword
```

In my Makefile, I have the following lines:

```
test-db:
    echo "create database dbname_test" | mysql -u root -h database -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

This does not work, as I get the following output when running my test pipeline:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'database' (115) make: *** [Makefile:10: test-db] Error 1
```

Is there a way I can access the values in my .env file in my makefile?

Comment: It would be easier to help if (a) you included the command line make invoked that generated this error (e.g., is the problem that `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` is empty?  Or something else?) and (b) you used code block formatting for the errors instead of text quoting: the latter wraps which makes it hard to read errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should add a blank space between `-p` and `${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}`

```
echo "create database dbname_test" | mysql -u root -h database -p ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding a space caused mysql to ask for a password, but strangely, removing the space again seemed to jog Make's memory, to the extent that the target now works. So this is ... odd. Maybe there's some sort of cache at play. Anyhow, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.